# Trouble with getting a bubble chart working in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Going to need a bubble chart for something I was working on and was using http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269 as an example. My data will be coming in as a flat format, so I wouldn't need to process the node tree and flatten it, so I removed that part.

Problem is that after removing that and simplifying the rest, it doesn't seem to do anything with the data. I'm guessing I have the data formatted incorrectly somehow, but I'm not sure.

http://tributary.io/inlet/b54cdb7104c40b1d7df3
I get no errors on it running, but I obviously have to be missing something here, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your data is flat,  the pack layout expects [hierarchical data](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#children).  You have to give it at least one `children` of your root node:

```
var json = {
  "data": {
    "children": [{ //<-- needs a child...
      "name": "test",
      "value": 55
    }, {
      "name": "test2",
      "value": 34
    }]
  }
};
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var json = {
      "data": {
        "children": [{
          "name": "test",
          "value": 55
        }, {
          "name": "test2",
          "value": 34
        }]
      }
    };

    var diameter = 960,
      format = d3.format(",d"),
      color = d3.scale.category20c();

    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
      .sort(null)
      .size([diameter, diameter])
      .padding(1.5);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter)
      .attr("height", diameter)
      .attr("class", "bubble");


    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(json.data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name + ": " + format(d.value);
      });

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yep, that is what I was missing. Thank you.